# jquery lightbox gallery caption position

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox

I am new to css and jquery, so sorry for my stupid question and I'd appreciate any help!
I liked this lightbox gallery https://kawshar.github.io/lightboxgallery/ to implement on my website. The only thing that I'd like to change is that the caption box goes under the image not on top of it (because it hides it)
Thanks very much in advance! 
Elitsa

Comment: You can reduce the opacity.! you cannot keep it under if you try it won't be visible.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some magic CSS generated via the lightbox javascript, **so this may cause issues**, but simply setting this will pop it below:

```
.lightboxgallery-image-content {
  position: static;
}
```

This is because currently it's set to `position: absolute;` on top of the image.

Comment: Worked like a charm after I updated it in both css lightbox files! thank you

Comment: Happy it helped! Feel free to mark as correct if so.

Comment: This snippet pushes the description down so only the first line is visible

Comment: I agree @Janis its not an ideal solution. To do something more robust would require some more serious overrides to jquery's lightbox.